# Downvote because of a wrong comment on an answer by the author?

Tags: support, voting

Should you downvote an answer whose main text is correct, but is followed-up by a wrong comment from the answer's author?

In other words, I wonder whether comments should be regarded as belonging to an answer just as well as the answer's "main" text, if the comments are by the answer's author. If so, the comment may be confusing, so the answer would deserve a downvote. But this could in turn confuse readers that think that the vote only classifies the answer's main text.

Therefore, I am not sure what I should do if I see an answer whose main text is correct, but which has a wrong comment from the same author.

Comment: I would counter comment rather than downvoting the answer.

Comment: Sometimes the comment chain shows that the answerer has no idea what they're talking about, and that the answer is not as correct as it previously appeared.  (Popular case: answer claims that snippet A is 500% faster than snippet B, then the comments reveal the measurement was made without compiler optimizations)

Comment: @BenVoigt Looks like we need a more concise example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is the answer in question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42535333/34509 . The wrong comment is "I don't think it does: ..." (well literally I think it is not wrong in itself, because he may well think that it doesn't. But that sort of comment usually implies to the reader that he states that it doesn't, because the author of the comment was the answerer and usually what one thinks is also what one would assert to others if one had to).

Comment: @Johannes Well, I see what you mean. Not great of a question though, and also that particular answer isn't really a pearl.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah. I tend to think commenting on these will lower my reputation. If I were asked to quantify a user's reputation algorithmically, one measure surely would be his percentage of comments and answers to high quality questions and comments. So I usually will stay away of commenting to these, since recently.

Comment: Related to Ben's comment: The answer code runs correctly, but it contains sub-optimal / obsolete / redundant stuff. Someone points this out in a comment but instead of repairing their answer the author attempts to defend the bad code. Sometime the bad code is due to the author having an important misunderstanding of how the language works, and we really don't want the OP or future readers assimilating such bad habits.

Comment: (cont) A classic example of this in the Python tag is people who don't grok how types work in Python who litter their code with redundant "casting" calls, eg they pass a string expression or even a string literal to the `str()` constructor. The constructor simply returns a reference to the original string object, so it's harmless, but it's still pointless, and it indicates that the perpetrator doesn't understand fundamental things about Python objects.

Comment: (cont)We really don't want them passing such wrong notions onto the newbies. Still, I try to deal with this in the comments and only downvote if they refuse to fix their answer or acknowledge the validity of my criticisms (which I generally back up with docs &/or examples).

Comment: So you'd upvote a comment, leaving the OP's reputation unchanged, but you downvote the answer costing the OP reputation? That hardly seems fair...

Comment: Some SE sites delete comments randomly. So really the question/answer should be updated. If OP updates it to your liking, you can reverse your downvote as a "reward" if you want.

Comment: Is flagging the comment as **not constructive** a good idea?

Answer (score 11):

If the incorrect comment is in *actual comment form* and not just an addendum at the end of the question, then no. It's clearly separate (yet related) to the answer. You should respond with your own comment asking why the author thinks that, and/or show evidence to the contrary. Comments are for clarification; this seems like a clear cut case of 'clarification needed', either on your part or the author's.

Also note that, while your vote is your vote to cast as you please (more or less), the tooltips for the voting buttons indicate that voting helps indicate an answer's *usefulness*, not necessarily its accuracy or its ability to address the question's problem directly (a helpful answer could provide a way for OP to get the solution they need without actually providing the solution itself, for example).

This is obviously assuming that there are *some* accuracies in the answer. If an answer says "JavaScript is the same thing as Java, but you can just write a `lie` in IE8 using the `new Promise( /* executor */ function(reject, resolve) { ... } );` syntax", well... no part of that is correct; neither the introductory sentence, nor the name of the function, nor the syntax of the code.

However, an answer that says "You can use a JS Promise for that" and then provides correct syntax, and a reasonable use of the feature, but then signs off by saying "Promises were introduced in ECMAScript 4, so they're supported in every browser" would, IMO not be downvote-worthy, even though that last line is obviously wrong (in several ways). Either edit the incorrect line out/to be correct, or leave a comment explaining why it's not a correct statement.

Comment: By definition, the *usefulness* of an answer is the quality of its use for the given purpose. If it is inaccurate, then it most certainly would not be useful as it would have no quality of use. Also, to note, comments are mostly seen as contribution nowadays, and are essentially as difficult to remove as answers (aside from the auto deletion set).

Comment: @TravisJ No, as has been discussed on meta before, technical accuracy is only one aspect of usefulness. It could start you thinking down a certain path that leads you to the answer, or it could make you curious about something and lead you to look up what you're wondering about, helping you to find what you're looking for. *Usefulness* is very nuanced.

Comment: Sorry, but if an answer is inaccurate, it is useless. Some semblence of accuracy may shed light on situations, but if there is literally *no accuracy* then there is no quality. You cannot just redefine words because "uhm, meta says so". **incorrect, wrong, erroneous, careless, faulty, imperfect, flawed, defective, unsound, unreliable**, these are synonymous with inaccurate.

Comment: @TravisJ You're free to use your votes in a less nuanced way but you are not free to restrict everyone else to the same narrow interpretation. Also, "no accuracy" is not the same as "inaccurate". On a sliding scale covering multiple aspects of an answer, 9 aspects could be accurate, and one aspect inaccurate, and the post would not have "no accuracy". Understandably, a post where there is "*no* accuracy" is highly unlikely to be useful, but there is not a *certainty* even then. But this explanation might be lost on you, if you do not favor a holistic approach.

Comment: It isn't interpretation, it is fact. We deal with facts here, and that is why having things like MCVE's are so popular; because they are easily verifiable. You use the word nuance, but it seems more like agenda. For example, downvoting an old answer in order to delete it would fall in your interpretation as nuance, whereas to most other users, that looks like agenda.

Comment: @TravisJ You're wrong, I'm afraid, and your prejudice is starting to show now that you're using specific examples. My participation in SOCVR is totally irrelevant to this, and, in case you missed it, downvoting for that reason has been expressly banned by CMs already. That's also not at all the kind of nuance I'm talking about (obviously, since I'm showing how an answer could be *useful*, not *useless*, as your words in my mouth suggest. But if you have a problem with something we're doing right now, feel free to bring it up in a Meta question or in the SOCVR chatroom.

Comment: @TravisJ Since you appreciate facts, here's one: it's a fact that different people think in different ways, and learn better following different methods. To you, an answer that has an inaccuracy may be useless. Someone else may be capable of reading it and using that answer to jumpstart a thought process that they otherwise would not have followed. You seem stuck on the notion that something is not useful, and yet here I am giving various explanations of how that thing could still be useful. This effect you're experiencing is called cognitive dissonance. You are biased toward a previous belief

Comment: I am highlighting your casual dismissal of technical accuracy in this answer, because it has been a topic of recent discussion. That you hand wave and make personal attacks only shows the amount of agenda you would rather pursue. This tool you are using is called an *ad hominem* attack. With regards to voting, I have been very consistent, and your notion that bias is effecting that is neither here nor there.

Comment: Accuracy is very important, moreover if there is partial inaccuracy it would be wrong to call an entire post inaccurate. I already stated this though, when I noted *Some semblence of accuracy may shed light on situations, but if there is literally no accuracy then there is no quality.*

Comment: @TravisJ Not quite; cognitive dissonance is shown in the arguments and statements of one's beliefs, not in their personal character, which is what an *ad hominem* attack is. At any rate, I don't want to get into the probabilities regarding you bringing up a specific example of a one-time event on meta. The point here seems to be that my answer was misinterpreted by you, because I don't feel like I casually dismissed *anything*. While I disagree that your argument re: "*no* accuracy" has much or any ground here, I will revise my answer to clarify that part.

Comment: The last paragraph (added in the edit) makes it very clear what you mean by partial inaccuracy, and also makes it very clear that an answer can definitely have some usefulness even if it is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 6):

In general, no. Comments should not be counted as part of an answer. This is for several reasons:

- It's misleading to someone reading the answer who might think there is something wrong with it when it's actually fine and the problem is with one of the comments
- It can be another way of enabling [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions?rq=1). The usual way chameleon questions happen is when the OP keeps editing the question after answers have already been given. If they are able to ask follow up questions in comments, and the answerer's answers to these follow up questions are counted as part of their answer, then we have the same situation. It's not fair to people answering questions - even if the person asking the follow up question is not the OP - because they answer on the basis of their knowledge of the *original* question. Follow up questions should be asked and answered with the understanding that they are separate from, and in addition to, the original question and answer.
- There should be a way of imparting knowledge and advice of a speculative or partial nature that isn't held to the same standards as an answer. There also should be a way of suggesting a fruitful avenue of investigation to someone without being obliged to do it yourself and provide references and so on. At the moment the comment/answer distinction is one way of facilitating this. If comments are effectively being upgraded in status to answers then this distinction is removed. Of course, non-answerers may still provide this kind of help in comments, but why should an answerer be excluded from this?

The one kind-of exception would be in the situation where an answer is of low quality, and you ask for clarification on something or make a suggestion for improvement in a comment rather than downvoting immediately, but the comment in reply indicates that no such improvement will be forthcoming. In that case it's really a delayed downvote on the answer, not on the comment per se. If the answer is correct, don't downvote.